# How to make pagination with Database category codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am new at codeigniter. I have a problem with codeigniter's pagination.
I tried to search google, youtube and codeigniter documentation but I didn't find anything.
I can implement a simple pagination but I need to create multi pagination with a database in one table.

Anyone that can help me please?

My database:

```
product:
id category title image
1  burger   a     a.jpg
2  burger   b     b.jpg
3  burger   c     c.jpg
4  pizza    d     d.jpg
5  pizza    e     e.jpg
6  pizza    f     f.jpg
```

The result that I want is pagination in one page
(pagination category burger by burger,pizza by pizza)

and my url is  http://localhost/test-ci1/

Code in `Model`:

```
<?php
class Product_model extends CI_Model {
    function get_burgers($category="", $limit, $start) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('product');

        if($category) {
            $this->db->where('category',$category);
        }
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_total($category="") {
        $this->db->select('count(*) AS num_row');
        $this->db->from('product');

        if($category) {
            $this->db->where('category',$category);
        }
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row()->num_row;
    }
}
```

in the `Controller`:

```
     <?php
class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('product_model','product');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Product_model');
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data = array();
        $per_page =2;
        $data["pizza"] = $this->product->get_burgers('pizza', $per_page, $page);
        $total_pizza = $this->product->get_total('pizza');
        $limit= 2;
        $link_pizza = 'http://localhost/test-ci1/pizza';
        $data['pagination_pizza'] = $this->pagination($total_pizza,$limit,$link_pizza);

       $data["burgers"] = $this->product->get_burgers('burger', $per_page, $page);
        $total_burger = $this->product->get_total('burger');
        $limit = 2;
        $link_burger = 'http://localhost/test-ci1/index/burger';
        $data['pagination_burger'] = $this->pagination($total_burger,$limit,$link_burger);

        $this->load->view('home_page_view',$data);
    }

    private function pagination($total ,$per_page ,$link) {

        $config['base_url'] = $link;
        $config['total_rows'] = $total;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        return $this->pagination->create_links();
    }

}
```

and in my `View`:

```
<body>

<h1>Pizza</h1>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($pizza as $val) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $val->title; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<?php echo $pagination_pizza; ?>
<hr>

<h1>Burger</h1>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($burgers as $val) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $val->title; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<?php echo $pagination_burger; ?>

</body>
```

and my result:

```
Pizza

    pizza1
    burger2

12>
Burger

    burger1
    assasa

12>
```

Comment: What html your foreach at the view outputs? Can you edit your question to add this? Most probably the error is on the html that gets outputted ther

Comment: ok I will edit now wait

Comment: Now I am edit already

Comment: Can you add the markup code that gets outputted? It will be something like `<ul><li><a href="blablah/20">2</a></li>` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you haven't developed your model pagination. You should add a function that does the pagination for you while extracting only the wanted rows from the database.

For your example something like this in your model will do:

```
function get_burgers($category="", $limit, $start) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('product');

        if($category) {
            $this->db->where('category',$category);
        }
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

And in your controller instead of fetching just one burger you should

```
$data["burgers"] = $this->burger_model->get_burgers($category, $config["per_page"], $page);
```

And change your foreach in your view to iterate through the `burgers`

Comment: Hi brother I try to followwing ur code but still has error. U can see my update ur code on up .

Comment: The `$config` array is not visible outside your pagination function. Try adding it as a class variable with `protected $config` just after your class declaration and then use it everywhere with `$this->config`. Or you can use another variable for `per_page` assigned on your index function

Comment: Hi brother now the limit is ok , and the problam is unvarible $page and when I click link on pagination 
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
my url site is http://localhost/test-ci1/

Comment: U can see my controller update and result update on up

Comment: `$per_page` is your `$limit` and `$page` is the beginning for your query ($start). You should fix the variable names first and then check.

Comment: Hi brother now i'm try to fixed ther erro now is no have .but the last problam is when I click to the pagination the page is not found

Comment: Can you show us the outputted HTML at the pagination section? What kind of link do you get at your Pagination numbers?

Comment: when I clik number 2 of pagination :  page is not found

Comment: when I click number 2 of paginatin the link is  http://localhost/test-ci1/index/burger?per_page=2   adn the page not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93881/discussion-between-sotoz-and-user307709).